# Non-linear polynomials are not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that polynomial $p(x)$ with $\text{deg} p(x)\geqslant 2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$.

**My proof:** Let $p(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$ then for $\epsilon=1$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^1$ with $|x-y|\leqslant \delta$ we have $|p(x)-p(y)|<1.$

Hence we get $|p(n\delta)-p(0)|\leqslant |p(n\delta)-p(n\delta-\delta)|+\dots+|p(2\delta)-p(\delta)|+|p(\delta)-p(0)|<1+1+\cdots+1=n.$ Thus $|p(n\delta)-p(0)|\leqslant n$.

WLOG we can suppose that $p(x)$ is monic and not contains free term, i.e. $p(x)=x^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\dots+a_1x, \qquad p(0)=0$ and we can write in the following form: $p(x)=x^k\left(1+\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{x}+\dots+\dfrac{a_1}{x^{k-1}}\right)$. Since $\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{x}+\dots+\dfrac{a_1}{x^{k-1}}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Then for $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ $\exists M>0$ such that for $x>M$ we have $\left|\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{x}+\dots+\dfrac{a_1}{x^{k-1}}\right|<\epsilon.$ Hence for $x>M$ we have $(1-\epsilon)x^k<p(x)<(1+\epsilon)x^k$.
But for $x>\max\{M,\sqrt[k]{\frac{n}{1-\epsilon}}\}$ we have $p(x)>n$. Moreover, we have $|p(n\delta)|<n$.

How to get contradiction? Can anyone help please with this last moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved that $p(k\delta )\leq k$ and $p(x) \geq (1-\varepsilon ) x^n $ hence $$k\geq p(k\delta )\geq (1-\varepsilon )(k\delta )^n $$ thus $$1\geq (1-\varepsilon )k^{n-1}\delta^n$$ for all sufficiently large $k\in\mathbb{N}$ which is impossible. That gives a contadiction.

Comment: Nice help! Thank you very much! +1

Answer (score 1):

Fix  $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ $\exists M>0$

Choose $n > \max \{M/δ, \left(\dfrac{1}{δ^n (1-ϵ)}\right)^{(1/(n-1))} \}$

Therefore, we have $(1)$ $nδ > M$ and $(2)$ $(1-ϵ)(nδ)^n > n$

$p(nδ) > (1-ϵ)(nδ)^n$ by $(1)$

$(1-ϵ)(nδ)^n > n$ by $(2)$

$p(nδ)-p(0) > n - p(0) > 0$ since $p(0) = 0$ and $n > 0$

$|p(nδ)-p(0)| > |n - p(0)| > n$

This lead to contradiction to $|p(nδ)-p(0)| \leqslant n$ in the first place.